# Doctrine with two databases with the same structure

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In my application (ZF2 + Doctrine) I have to use two separate databases with technical data of vehicles. Both databases have the same structure but the data is from different countries.

What would be the best approach to use one set of entities but connecting to different database selected by vehicle origin.

In example if vehicle origin is UK then use DB1, if Germany use DB2.

Comment: If the two databases have the same structure, is there any reason to keep them apart?

Comment: They are provided by 3rd party company with their daily updates. I don't want to change their structure.

Comment: You can look at this [thread](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/122), it might help you.

Comment: Got info from the supplier that there is no overlapping in IDs and the database can be merged without problems. I'm going to go this way but the problem seems interesting for me and I'm still interested how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got two databases with the same structure, it is typically best to merge them to reduce your maintenance efforts and to avoid maintaining them differently, among other things.
However, if you do need to keep the databases separate, you might consider whether `Multiple Table Inheritance` (or `Class Table Inheritance`) could be a good solution for you.

I use Multiple Table Inheritance to manage calendar events.  Every calendar event has a start date, a start time, an end date and an end time.  However, events that are meetings could also have data like agendas and attendee lists; events that are business lunches could have data like reservations and expense report items; and events that are business trips could have data like itineraries and confirmation codes.  With Multiple Table Inheritance, there is a single table (class) with a row for every event and a column for each type of data that is common to all events.  Then there is a collection of tables for unique types of events and the unique types of data that are common only to those events.  I might have a 'Meetings' table, a 'Lunches' table and a 'Trips' table in addition to my primary 'Events' table.  The data in the unique tables is mapped to the Events table with a discriminator column in the Events table that tells Doctrine which unique table the event is associated with.

The theory behind Multiple Table Inheritance doesn't really match what you are trying to do because the intent is to combine datasets that have different structures, not datasets that have the same structure.  However, what it does offer you is the opportunity to combine data from tables that you wish to keep separate for whatever reason.  It will also give you the flexibility to change the structure of the two tables if you ever find a need to do so.

Comment: I use this as well, but I think this is a different issue. I reckon one of the ways could be using a factory with injected config selected by origin.